# Angular 6 - object property not loading on page for some items but does for others

Tags: angular, angular6, frontend

I'm trying to show the quantity of items, which is a property for each item, that are included for each package in my store catalogue page.

```
<div *ngIf="product.package_items">
     <ul *ngFor="let item of product.package_items" style="list-style: none">
         <li>- {{ item.name }} <b>x {{ item.quantity }}</b></li>
     </ul>
</div>
```

This code applies to every package in every page. For one of the package pages, the code works fine.

[showing item.quantity](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vt9co.png)

The package object shows the item.quantity on page load. However, for packages in other pages, the item.quantity does not show.

[not showing item.quantity](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ayxev.png)

The package object for the working packages is incoming as:
[working package](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XRDXd.png)

which is the same as the non-working package:
[not working package](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AonkA.png)

The odd thing is that if I insert any other property instead of quantity, it shows on all pages, e.g. item.price shows on every page. This doesn't seem to be a lifecycle issue since other properties show up fine.

**UPDATE:** So there are 4 package pages in total, originally only 1 page had packages showing quantities, now it is 2 pages including the first one. In fact, the example given here is from the page that suddenly now works. So there are still 2 pages that don't work, and I haven't changed any code.

**Additional code**:  From the .ts file (removed cart related methods, and imports)

```
@Component({
  selector: 'product-tile',
  templateUrl: './product-tile.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./product-tile.component.scss'],
  animations: [fastFade]
})
export class ProductTileComponent implements OnInit {
  @Input('product')
  product: Product;
  @Input()
  projectCart: String;
  symbol: '$';
  constructor(
    private projectService: ProjectService,
    private productService: ProductService,
    public afs: AngularFirestore,
    private router: Router
  ) {}

  ngOnInit() {
    this.updateQuantity();
  }
}
```

**FINAL UPDATE**:
Fixed issue, not an Angular problem after all. Just had to reset the data cache from the server. It was worth troubleshooting via piping the JSON, was a good heads up.

Comment: What do you get when you pipe the item as JSON? `<pre>{{ item | json }}</pre>`

Comment: The quantity property is missing on the packages where it doesn't show. Still unsure why that would be the case.

Comment: Are you getting this data from an API? If so check the response has the property quantity.

Comment: Yeah, I'm getting it from an API, using the JSON pipe, it shows that the quantity property is missing for some reason. Yet, if I select the non-working package from the catalogue to take me to its individual package page, the quantities show up.

Comment: I think you need to share more code.  If your API is providing a response with the correct keys, but the output from piping the JSON doesn't show the key then inbetween there is something happening in your controller or service.  You might need to step through your code in the console and see where that's happening.

Comment: @mtpultz this is the ts file for the catalogue page, I've removed the irrelevant methods.

Comment: You'll need to provide more since this doesn't show response handling or the path your data takes before reaching the template.  I only shows an input of the product data.  I would assume at this point that the `@Input product` is the same as the piped JSON and the issue is likely upstream of this component unless you're manipulating the incoming data in this controller.

Comment: @mtpultz Turns out it was a caching problem after all, had the backend dev reset the cache on those pages. Thanks for the help anyway!